# Arrange break lines html text code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I wan't to arrange breaklines in vscode, I wan't all lines to be the same size more or less.

I always use extensions for formatting the code like prettier, but they make it worse as they insert break lines to long lines. But they don't fix shorter lines, ending up with a lot of small lines. Something like this:
[image]